# Formula to calculate p-values for the fixed component of a mixed effects model

Tags: mixed-model, p-value

I’m building an algorithm to obtain a mixed effects model. So I am not using lme or lmer or anything.
I was able to get my estimates and standard errors.
Now I want to get the p-values for the fixed component of the model. Maybe it is really simple, but I don’t know how to do it.
Does anyone know the formula to calculate the p-values of the fixed component of a mixed effects model?

Comment: See appendix A in this paper:
https://www.jstatsoft.org/index.php/jss/article/view/v082i13/1186

Comment: @RobertLong thank you!!!